# Opengl using freeglut on linux shows only a transparent window

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glut, freeglut

I am trying to use freeglut3 on  linux mint 20 to do some basic openGL ( my teacher forced me to use glut/freeglut with c++ ). I am just trying to make a black window to show on screen but only a transparent window shows up and it doesn't close until it shows Segmentation fault (core dumped)

here is my code

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void init()
{
    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(300, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("Linux TEST");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

I am using `g++ main.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglut` to compile the code

Here is the output [image: screenshot]

Comment: You've specified an alpha value of zero in the call to `glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0)`.  Try `glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1)` instead.

Comment: @G.M. tried that same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a double buffered context using...

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
```

But you never call [`glutSwapBuffers`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node21.html).  Change your `display` function to...

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/rmcTojq) tried it but no success

Comment: Adding the call to `glutSwapBuffers` gives me the expected result so I'm not sure what else to recommend I'm afraid.

Comment: are you on windows? on windows this code works but not on linux

Comment: No, I'm on Suse Linux with an old Nvidia card (Nouveau driver) and libglut.so.3 .

Comment: I also have libglut.so.3 installed. How do you build the programs ? do you use cmake ? ( I don't think this would be a solution , I am just curious )